# Operator overloading outside class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

There are two ways to overload operators for a C++ class:

#### Inside class

```
class Vector2
{
public:
    float x, y ;

    Vector2 operator+( const Vector2 & other )
    {
        Vector2 ans ;
        ans.x = x + other.x ;
        ans.y = y + other.y ;
        return ans ;
    }
} ;
```

#### Outside class

```
class Vector2
{
public:
    float x, y ;
} ;

Vector2 operator+( const Vector2& v1, const Vector2& v2 )
{
    Vector2 ans ;
    ans.x = v1.x + v2.x ;
    ans.y = v1.y + v2.y ;
    return ans ;
}
```

(Apparently in C# you can only use the "outside class" method.)

In C++, which way is more correct?  Which is preferable?

Comment: Did you mean for the member `operator+` to be non-const as this gives the non-member function a head start in 'correcterness' as it will work in more situations?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532991/what-is-the-difference-between-overloading-an-operator-inside-or-outside-a-class also has some answers

Comment: For the record, in C# you can use either. "Outside class" operators (or other methods) in C# are called [extension methods](https://web.archive.org/web/20201121050945/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The basic question is **"Do you want conversions to be performed on the left-hand side parameter of an operator?"**. If yes, use a free function. If no, use  a class member.

For example, for `operator+()` for strings, we want conversions to be performed so we can say things like:

```
string a = "bar";
string b = "foo" + a;
```

where a conversion is performed to turn the `char * "foo"` into an `std::string`. So, we make `operator+()` for strings into a free function.

Comment: So if you used the member function version, you COULD NOT have `"foo" + a`, __but you could__ have `a + "foo"`

Comment: @Roger, aww you are fast. I already deleted my comment right away since it wasn't on-topic. Your barton-nackman trickery looks neat, didn't think of that at all xD

Comment: There are implications for how you declare the non-member operators for templates, compare http://codepad.org/ACNeZcCf vs http://codepad.org/3jbvxRN9/.  The former is called http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barton-Nackman_trick.

Comment: @Roger, now this comment thread looks fun. Some reverse_iterator rushed over it :) I agree, this is a problem with std::string too. You can't do `std::string s; s = s + +'a';` and expect 'a' to be added since the second argument expects `CharT` but it deduces to `int` oO I was about to recommend `identity<CharT>::type` as the parameter, so it doesn't participate in deduction, but your friend function beats it all xD

Answer (score 24):

First: the two different ways are really "overload as a member" and "overload as a non-member", and the latter has two different ways to write it (as-friend-inside class definition and outside class definition).  Calling them "inside class" and "outside class" is going to confuse you.

---

Overloads for +=, +, -=, -, etc. have a special pattern:

```
struct Vector2 {
  float x, y;
  Vector2& operator+=(Vector2 const& other) {
    x += other.x;
    y += other.y;
    return *this;
  }
  Vector2& operator-=(Vector2 const& other) {
    x -= other.x;
    y -= other.y;
    return *this;
  }
};
Vector2 operator+(Vector2 a, Vector2 const& b) {
  // note 'a' is passed by value and thus copied
  a += b;
  return a;
}
Vector2 operator-(Vector2 a, Vector2 const& b) { return a -= b; } // compact
```

This pattern allows the conversions mentioned in the other answers for the LHS argument while simplifying the implementation considerably.  (Either member or non-member allows conversions for the RHS when it's passed either as a `const&` or by value, as it should be.)  Of course, this only applies when you do actually want to overload both += and +, -= and -, etc., but that is still common.

---

Additionally, you sometimes want to declare your non-member op+, etc. as [friends](http://codepad.org/ACNeZcCf) within the class definition using the [Barton-Nackman trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barton-Nackman_trick), because due to quirks of templates and overloading, it may not be found [otherwise](http://codepad.org/3jbvxRN9).

Comment: But if you pass `a` by reference, `Vector2& operator+=( Vector2& a, const Vector2& b )`, you could achieve the same end

Comment: @bobobobo: Op+= often needs access to non-public members, and in that case it's easier to make it a member than a friend.  Op= *must* be a member and it's also convenient to group +=, -=, etc. with op=.

Answer (score 6):

There is an excellent discussion of this issue in Meyer's Effective C++: Item 24 is "Declare non-member functions when type conversions should apply to all parameters" and Item 46 is "Define non-member functions inside templates when type conversions are desired".