# question regarding "this" pointer in c++

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, this

i have been given class with int variables x and y in private, and an operator overload function,

```
class Bag{
private:
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    Bag();
    ~Bag();
    //.......
    //.....etc
};


Bag operator+ (Bag new) const{
    Bag result(*this);   //what does this mean?
    result.x += new.x;         
    result.y += new.y;
}
```

What is the effect of having "Bag result(*this);" there?.

Comment: Is the `operator+` function missing a `return` statement?

Comment: This is not looks like valid C++ -- new is keyword

Comment: If you wish to create operators, I suggest looking at `Boost.Operators`. They have grouped similar operators together (like `+=` and `+`) and writing only one of the group grants you the others for free :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Bag result(*this)` creates a copy of the object on which the operator function was called.

Example if there was:

```
sum = op1 + op2;
```

then `result` will be a copy of `op1`.

Since the `operator+` function is doing a sum of its operands and returning the sum, we need a way to access the operand op1 which is done through the `this` pointer.

Alternatively we could have done:

```
Bag result;
result.x = (*this).x + newobj.x; // note you are using new which is a keyword.
result.y = (*this).y + newobj.y; // can also do this->y instead
return result;
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code would look like:

```
class Bag {
public:
  Bag();
  Bag(Bag const& other); // copy ctor, declared implicitly if you don't declare it
  ~Bag();

  Bag operator+(Bag const& other) const;

private:
  int x;
  int y;
};

Bag Bag::operator+(Bag const& other) const {
  Bag result (*this);
  result.x += other.x;         
  result.y += other.y;
  return result;
}
```

The implicit "current object" for member functions is pointed to by a special value named *this*.  Then `*this` gets that object (by dereferencing *this*), and it is used to construct (via the copy constructor) another Bag named *result*.

I suspect this code is taken from a homework assignment, so you might not be able to use the [one true addition operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425906/operator-overloading-c-outside-class/2425965#2425965) pattern, but it is common and you should be aware of it:

```
struct Bag {
  //...
  Bag& operator+=(Bag const& other) {
    x += other.x;
    y += other.y;
    return *this; // return a reference to the "current object"
    // as almost all operator=, operator+=, etc. should do
  }
};

Bag operator+(Bag a, Bag const& b) {
  // notice a is passed by value, so it's a copy
  a += b;
  return a;
}
```

Comment: That is a dangerous way of writing op+() - the first parameter will be sliced, and if there was intended to be any polymorphic behaviour in the function based on it, there won't be. It's much better to make both parameters const references, and create the copy within the function.

Comment: @Neil: Copying within the function also slices; it's much better to use this pattern until you need to change it.  Also see http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/ which promotes the same idiom for operator=.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, tell the code writer not to use `new` as the variable name — it's a keyword. Also, remeber to `return result;`. And either pass by const-reference or directly modify the `new` bag.

---

Inside a struct/class, `this` is a pointer to itself. Therefore, `*this` is a reference to the whole Bag instance itself.

The statement `Bag result(a_bag_reference)` will call the copy constructor of `Bag`, which makes a copy of `a_bag_reference` into `result`.

Therefore,

```
Bag result(*this);
```

makes a copy of itself, then store into `result`. This makes the next 2 statements

```
result.x += new.x;
result.y += new.y;
```

do not affect the instance itself (i.e. `this->x` and `this->y` are kept constant).

Answer (score 2):

The `operator+` function returns a copy.  The statement:

```
Bag result(*this);
```

Is making a copy of *this* object to return to the caller.
According to the signature, it must return a value, so it is making a copy and then adding the `new` object.

Answer (score 2):

`Bag result(*this);` is declaring a variable `result` and invoking its **copy constructor**.

You can imagine C++ automatically declares a default copy constructor for all classes. Its job is simply to initialize an object using another object:

```
Bag::Bag(Bag const& src) {
   x = src.x;
   y = src.y;
}
```

The expression `*this` may look a little unsettling, but is just the usual horror of C++ when you deal with `&` parameters.