# How is std::map overloading its subscript [] operator ? C++

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, hashmap

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
int main(void) {
  std::map<char, int> mapint;

  mapint.insert({'a', 1});
  mapint.insert({'b', 2});

  // subscript operator is overloaded to return iterator.second (the value with key 'a')
  int ex = mapint['a'];
  std::cout << ex << std::endl;
  // Why does this NOT traslate to 1=10 ?
  // instead it replaces or creates pair <'a',10>...
  mapint['a'] = 10;

  for (auto i : mapint) {
    std::cout << i.first << "," << i.second << std::endl;
  }
  
  // OUTPUT
// 1
// a,10
// b,2

  return 0;
}
```

How is the `map` operator being overloaded? I tried looking at the code for map but i couldn't find anything to answer my question...
I want to make something similar for one of my classes and i think figuring this out should help alot!

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: I am sorry but i still don't see it...

Comment: Scroll down to "Array Subscripting" in the top answer of the duplicate

Comment: I read that part but it didn't solve my question.[This looks like what am looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425906/operator-overloading-outside-class?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: It's unclear to me what your question is then

Comment: Lets say i have a class similar to a `map`. I want to have the same functionality of the map[] operator. I cant figure out how to have 
`int ex = mytype['a']; //Give item with key 'a'` 
`mytype['a'] = 10; // replace or create pair <'a',10>`

Comment: `mapint['a']` returns a reference to the value corresponding to key `'a'`. If there was no such value, it inserts one, default-initialized; and then returns a reference to this freshly inserted value.

Answer (score 1):

It basically just builds on top of existing methods found within map. It is implemented along the lines of...

```cpp
template<typename Key, typename Value>
struct map {

  // This operator cannot be declared 'const', since if the key 
  // is not found, a new items is automatically added. 
  Value& operator [] (const Key& key) {
    // attempt to find the key
    auto iter = find(key);

    // if not found... 
    if(iter == end()) {
    
      // insert new item (with a default value to start with)
      iter = insert(std::make_pair(key, Value()));
    }

    // return reference to the data item stored for 'key'
    return iter->second;    
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To overload the [] operator you can do as follows (in pseudo-code):

```
struct A
{
    your_return_type operator[](your_argument_list)
    {
        your implementation
    }
};
```

If you want to return a reference to some class member, then you may have to implement 2 versions of this operator, one `const`, which returns a non-modifiable reference, and one `non-const`, which returns a modifiable refence.

```
struct A
{
    your_modifiable_return_type_ref& operator[](your_argument_list)
    {
        your implementation
    }


    const your_non_modifiable_return_type_ref& operator[](your_argument_list) const
    {
        your implementation
    }
};
```